# Create Devise User and association they belong to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Having trouble figuring out how to setup this form.  I have two models Business and User.  Business has a `has_many :users association` and user has a `belong_to :business`.  Im trying to create an initial form to create a business and the first user (the owner).  This is my routes files:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' }
  root 'pages#index'

  resources :businesses do
      resources :users
  end
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

The business.rb

```
class Business < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :users
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

The user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :business
end
```

And here is the new.html.erb for the business route:

```
<div class="row center-xs">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1>New Business</h1>
        <%= simple_form_for @business do |b| %>
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                <%= b.input :name, label_html: {class: 'mdl-textfield__label'}, input_html: {class: 'mdl-textfield__input'}, required: true, label: "Business Name" %>
            </div><br>
            <%= b.simple_fields_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), validate: true) do |f| %>
                <%= devise_error_messages! %>
                <%= f.input :role, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: "owner" } %>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                    <%= f.input :name, label_html: {class: 'mdl-textfield__label'}, input_html: {class: 'mdl-textfield__input'}, required: true, label: "Your Name" %>
                </div><br>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                    <%= f.input :email, label_html: {class: 'mdl-textfield__label'}, input_html: {class: 'mdl-textfield__input'}, validate: true, required: true %>
                </div><br>
                <% if @minimum_password_length %>
                    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
                <% end %>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                    <%= f.input :password, label_html: {class: 'mdl-textfield__label'}, input_html: {class: 'mdl-textfield__input'}, autocomplete: "off", required: true %>
                </div><br>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, label_html: {class: 'mdl-textfield__label'}, input_html: {class: 'mdl-textfield__input'}, autocomplete: "off", required: true %>
                </div><br>
            <% end %>   
            <%= b.button :submit, "Sign up", class: 'mdl-button' %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to create a business I get an error that says:

```
 ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'user' for Business.)
```

Right now the controller is just the default controller generated by the scaffold:

```
def create
    @business = Business.new(business_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @business.save
        format.html { redirect_to @business, notice: 'Business was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @business }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @business.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def business_params
  params.require(:business).permit(:name, :user => [:email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation])
end
```

Comment: On which line does the error shows up?

Comment: Add to your Business model: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :users`. see [NestedAttributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Added that in and get the same error still

Answer (score 0):

In business controller rename :user key in permit function to :users_attributes

```
params.require(:business).permit(:name, :users_attributes => [:email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation])
```